# Recursive generator in Rust

Tags: recursion, rust, generator

I am trying to port this [python prime number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391111/2846140) to rust using [rust generators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Generator.html) and this [generator-to-iterator wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279122/2846140).

My problem is that the original implementation is recursive, and I didn't manage to get passed the following error:

```
error[E0720]: opaque type expands to a recursive type
  --> src/main.rs:27:29
   |
27 | fn recursive_generator() -> impl Iterator<Item = u64> {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expands to a recursive type
   |
   = note: expanded type is `GeneratorToIterator<[generator@src/main.rs:28:25: 
   48:6 {u64, (), impl std::iter::Iterator}]>`
```

Below is the implementation of the recursive generator producing this error:

```rust
fn recursive_generator() -> impl Iterator<Item = u64> {
    GeneratorToIterator(move || {
        // Yield a few values
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;

        // Initialize the inner generator
        let mut inner_value: u64 = 0;
        let mut inner_generator = recursive_generator();

        // Get the first value of the inner generator
        match inner_generator.next(){
             Some(x) => inner_value += x,
             None => {},
        }

        // Yield some other values
        yield 4;
        yield 5;
        yield 6;
    })
}
```

The full implementation (with the `GeneratorToIterator` definition) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/45ddea42c6965927761e51d3f0a1213b).

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488432/recursive-generator-in-rust-causing-cycle-error-workaround) but I did not manage to compile their `gen_to_iter` function.

EDIT: Thanks to @bluss answer, I've finally been able to implement [a working version of the prime number generator](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/95b769bc9b2c68bfcbb2fbcc86cac919#file-primegen-rs) in rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error [explanation E0720](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/error-index.html#E0720) mentions that an `impl Trait` type must expand to one that doesn't contain other `impl Trait` types, but here the type is of course recursive, since that's the point.

This can be worked around by using boxed trait objects instead - `Box<Iterator<Item=u64>>` works well here and avoids the problem.

Either adjust `recursive_generator` to return `Box<Iterator<Item=u64>>`, or change the line of the recursive call to use the boxed iterator just for that recursive case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just tried and both approaches work just fine! For the second solution I had to use [`let mut inner_generator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u64>> = Box::new(recursive_generator());`](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/45ddea42c6965927761e51d3f0a1213b#file-recgen-rs-L36-L37), can you confirm that this is what you meant?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your version with coercion or this version with cast are equivalent: `Box::new(f()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item=u64>`

Comment: Thanks again, I finally managed to get [my implementation](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/95b769bc9b2c68bfcbb2fbcc86cac919#file-primegen-rs) to work :)

Comment: It reminds me of this https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf  but I don't know the details very well. Have fun :)